# NodeJS - Read two numbers from input stream and print its sum to output stream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to solve a task that reads:
"Two whole numbers are defined in the standard input stream; each number is >= -32000 and <= 32000.
Print the sum of these numbers to the standard output stream."
Input:

```
1
2
```

Output:

```
3
```

My code is below:

```
let total = 0;
let numbers_counter = 0;
process.stdin.on('data', data => {
    numbers_counter++;
    total += parseInt(data);
    if (numbers_counter == 2) {
        process.stdout.write(total.toString(), () => {
            return process.exit()
        });    
    }   
})
process.stdin.on('end', () => {
    process.stdout.write(total.toString(), () => {
        return process.exit()
    });
})
```

The problem is that I'm getting a 'wrong answer' response (I don't know how my code is tested, the only output I see is 'wrong answer')

Any clue what needs to be changed?

Comment: https://repl.it/languages/nodejs, your code is fine at all.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, this is enough:

```
let total = 0;
let numbers_counter = 0;
process.stdin.on('data', data => {
    numbers_counter++;
    total += parseInt(data);
    if (numbers_counter == 2) {
        process.stdout.write(total.toString(), () => {
            return process.exit()
        });    
    }   
})
```

And I think this is simpler:

```
let total = 0;
let numbers_counter = 0;
process.stdin.on('data', data => {
    numbers_counter++;
    total += parseInt(data);
    if (numbers_counter == 2) {
        process.stdout.write(total.toString());
        process.exit();   
    }   
})
```

Perhaps you will pass if you don't exit the process?

Comment: thanks for your contribution!
If I don't pass process.exit() to the callback function, I see 'exception' in the output

I'm starting to think that there's something wrong with the test itself

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, both numbers were expected to be in one chunk of data